# Training an object detector using Cloud Machine Learning Engine

Tags: machine-learning, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to follow this protocol:
https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/training-an-object-detector-using-cloud-machine-learning-engine

but after

after

```
gsutil cp pet_train.record ${YOUR_GCS_BUCKET}/data/pet_train.record
```

I get

```
IOError: [Errno 28] No space left on device
```

then I did `df`

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
none            25669948 15408340   8934608  64% /
tmpfs             304340        0    304340   0% /dev
tmpfs             304340        0    304340   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1        5028480  4749764       240 100% /home
/dev/sda1       25669948 15408340   8934608  64% /etc/hosts
shm                65536        0     65536   0% /dev/shm
```

any idea what s going on there?

tyvm

Answer (score 0):

Yes: you filled up your disk:

```
/dev/sdb1        5028480  4749764       240 100% /home
```

You've used roughly 5Gb of disk space.  The training is trying to write more data, and the remaining 240K is too small for the current write.

Comment: but what is /dev/sdb1? Can i increase the space there? Thank you.

Comment: That's the device where your home directory resides.  This is a system configuration issue; increasing the size is something to take up with your system administrator.  It requires changing the size of that disk partition.  It's likely easier to identify a device where you can store more data -- again, something to take up with your sysadmin.